# VB.net classes - Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, object, instance

I'm working on an application in VB that is giving me some trouble. Coming from Java and C++, the class syntax for VB is peculiar. I have my main form, and a class I created called `WebElement`. I imported the class to `MainForm.vb` and declared an array of `WebElement`'s. When I try to set or get the `Name` attribute of the first element of my array of 'WebElement`'s, it gives me an error - **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object?"** What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

**Code** 
`MainForm.vb`

```
Imports MyProgram.WebElement

Public Class MainForm

    Private webpage(0 To 9) As WebElement
    Private pageNum As Integer = 0

    Private Sub openFile() Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
        webpage(pageNum).setName("rawr")
        MsgBox(webpage(pageNum).getName())
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

`WebElement.vb`

```
Public Class WebElement

    Private Name As String

    Public Function setName(ByRef n As String)
        Name = n
    End Function

    Public Function getName()
        Return Name
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
 Private webpage(0 To 9) As WebElement
```

declares an array of 10 elements that should be of type WebElement.
No element is present in the array. So every slot is Nothing (null in C#).
Calling a method on a null element will give the NullReferenceException

You should check you element before calling the method and, if it is null, create the element and assign it to the required slot

```
Private Sub openFile() Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    if webpage(pageNum) Is Nothing Then
       webpage(pageNum) = new WebElement()
    End If
    webpage(pageNum).setName("rawr")
    MsgBox(webpage(pageNum).getName())
End Sub
```

As a side note, why don't you try to use the NET syntax to implement class properties

```
Public Class WebElement

    Private Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

and then use it in your code

```
 webpage(pageNum).Name = "rawr"
 MessageBox.Show(webpage(pageNum).Name)
```

Comment: Alright that makes sense, I guess. I thought that by using the `setName()` function I was making it contain something, and therefore not be empty or "nothing/null". Thats strange.

Comment: The first thing is to create the WebElement instance, then, you have your object in memory, and you could call methods and set/get properties against the instance. Look at the answer from @cody gray to a very precise description of the concept

Answer (score 2):

You don't fill your array with `WebElements`, you only tell it what size it needs to be. So `webpage(pageNum)` is a null object.

Try

```
Private Sub openFile() Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    webpage(pageNum) = New WebElement()
    webpage(pageNum).setName("rawr")
    MsgBox(webpage(pageNum).getName())
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool, it works. So, it didn't work before because I wasn't actually declaring all the objects? I was just telling it that I needed 10 elements of that class?

Comment: @JoshI, sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner. I hope you got the answers you needed.

Answer (score 2):

The class syntax in VB.NET may be peculiar, but the *usage* of classes is very similar to Java and C++.

In particular, there is a difference between a *definition* of a class *type* (which you've written in `WebElement.vb` and imported into your `MainForm.vb` code file), and an *object* of that class type. The latter is the one that you're missing.

You need to create (instantiate) an object of the `WebElement` class type in your code. The array you have declared right now is empty (i.e., all of its elements are null). All you've done is *declared* it. The compiler doesn't create and fill it with objects until you ask it to do so.

You need to *initialize* the elements in the array with a new object. You do this by using the `New` keyword. The syntax looks like this:

```
webpage(0) = New WebElement()   ' initializes the first element in the array
                                ' with a new WebElement object
```

You can also initialize the array elements inline when you declare it, if you so choose. In order to make this magic happen, you omit the size from the left side of the declaration and use an initializer list on the right, like so:

```
Dim webpage() As WebElement = {
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement(),
                               New WebElement()
                              }
```

But this syntax gets pretty unwieldy for long arrays, so most people prefer looping over the elements of the array immediately after declaration and creating the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have created `webpage` array, but all of its elements are null, so `webpage(pageNum).setName("rawr")` dereferences a null object

Answer (score 0):

That means NullPointerException because the objects haven´t been initialized, just like in java.

try

`Private webpage(0 To 9) As New WebElement`